# не откликается на нажатия по пунктам меню

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Файл java

```
public class content_mainn extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
DrawerLayout drawer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            content_mainn.this, drawer, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    Button btn=findViewById(R.id.button);

}
public void OnClickbtn(View view){
   Log.d("TAG", "OnClickbtn1: кнопка");
    drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        Log.d("TAG", "onBackPressed: я здесь");
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Log.d("TAG", "onNavigationItemSelected: "+id);
    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onNavigationItemSelected: 1");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onNavigationItemSelected: 1");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onNavigationItemSelected: 1");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_tools) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onNavigationItemSelected: 1");
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}}
```

файл xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".content_mainn"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />



<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:onClick="OnClickbtn"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Когда нажимаю на пункт меню никакого сообщения  в logcat не выводится

Файл меню xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/menu_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_tools"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="@string/menu_tools" />
</group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сначала необходимо установить меню в NavigationView программно:

```
NavigationView nav_view = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
nav_view.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Log.d("TAG", "onNavigationItemSelected: "+id);
        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onNavigationItemSelected: 1");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onNavigationItemSelected: 1");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onNavigationItemSelected: 1");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tools) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onNavigationItemSelected: 1");
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Только уберите эту строку из NavigationView:
    **app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"**